# Why does liftM not destroy context?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm confused about how `liftM` preserves context, specifically in the case of the `Writer` monad.  I've been going through "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good" and am stuck on its explanation of `liftM`.

Here is an example:

```
ghci> runWriter $ liftM not $ Writer (True, "chickpeas")
(False,"chickpeas")
```

I understand the concept that `liftM` lifts the `not` function into the monad, applies it to the value inside (`True`), and either does nothing with the monoid ("chickpeas") or combines it with the identity monoid for strings ("").

However, the implementation of `liftM` is given as:

```
liftM :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b  
liftM f m = m >>= (\x -> return (f x))
```

Applying `f` to the `x` value inside of the monad being fed into the function makes sense.  However, if I execute `return (f x)`, why would I not get back whatever `f x` produces wrapped up in a *default* monad context?  In the `Writer` example above, I would expect `runWriter $ return (f x)` to produce `(False, "")` since the default `Writer string bool` instance has "" as its monoid value.

What am I missing?

Comment: As you said, it "*combines it with the identity monoid for strings (`""`)*". `return (not True)` is indeed `(False, "")`. Have you checked what the `m >>=` part does with that?

Comment: Or another hint: `m >>= (\x->return x)` is the same as `m`, not the same as `return x`. Not loosing the context is the whole point of monadic `>>=`.

Comment: `>>=` is going to combine the previous monoid value with the next one, so it'll be `"chickpeas" ++ ""`.

Comment: By the way, `fmap` is usually preferred over `liftM`, since it's more general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've focused so hard on `\x -> return (f x)` that you completely forgot about the `m >>=` that precedes it!

You are absolutely correct about what `return` does:

```
Control.Monad.Writer> return (not True) :: Writer String Bool
WriterT (Identity (False,""))
```

The bit you've forgotten about is the bind, which is implemented like this (up to some `newtype` and transformer nonsense):

```
m >>= f = (val', monoid <> monoid') where
    (val, monoid) = m
    (val', monoid') = f val
```

That `monoid'` part will be `""` in our case, but the `monoid` will be `"chickpeas"`, and so that will not be lost. In detail:

```
(True, "chickpeas") >>= (\x -> return (not x))
= { definition of bind }
(val', monoid <> monoid') where
    (val, monoid) = (True, "chickpeas")
    (val', monoid') = (\x -> return (not x)) val
= { substitute away val and monoid everywhere }
(val', "chickpeas" <> monoid') where
    (val', monoid') = (\x -> return (not x)) True
= { evaluate the lambda and not }
(val', "chickpeas" <> monoid') where
    (val', monoid') = return False
= { definition of return }
(val', "chickpeas" <> monoid') where
    (val', monoid') = (False, "")
= { substitute away val' and monoid' everywhere }
(False, "chickpeas" <> "")
= { evaluate <> }
(False, "chickpeas")
```

Comment: Right in front of me!  I suppose this is a corollary to the right identity law: `m >>= return` must equal `m`, which could also be written as `m >>= (\x -> return x)` must equal `m`.  `liftM` changes that last form to `m >>= (\x -> return (f x)` may change the value in `m` but not the context.  Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 3):

The key is the definition of `>>=` for `Writer`. The following is simplified, since `Writer` is defined in terms of `WriterT Identity`:

```
w >>= f = Writer (m <> n, b)
  where (m, a) = runWriter w
        (n, b) = runWriter (f a)
```

Now if we expand `liftM` with this definition for `>>=`, you can see how the monoidal writer-value is accumulated.

```
liftM f w = w >>= \x -> return (f x)

          {- expand definiton of (>>=) -}
          = Writer (m <> n, b)
                where (m, a) = runWriter w
                      (n, b) = runWriter ((\x -> return (f x)) a)

          {- apply (\x -> return (f x)) to its argument -}
          = Writer (m <> n, b)
                where (m, a) = runWriter w
                      (n, b) = runWriter (return (f a))

          {- expand definition of (return (f a)) -}
          = Writer (m <> n, b)
                where (m, a) = runWriter w
                      (n, b) = runWriter (Writer ("", f a))

          {- runWriter . Writer === id -}
          = Writer (m <> n, b)
                where (m, a) = runWriter w
                      (n, b) = ("", f a)

          {- inline 'n' and 'b' -}
          = Writer (m <> "", f a) where (m, a) = runWriter w

          {- "" is the identity element -}
          = Writer (m, f a) where (m, a) = runWriter w
```

From the final equation, you can see that `liftM f (Writer (m, a))` will apply `f` to the `a` value inside the `Writer`, while retaining the previous monoid value `m`.